# Want to know the length of a buffer C++

Tags: c++, qt, file, buffer, variable-length

I am new to C++ and programming and I would like to know if there is a way to get the length of a pointer.
Let's say Myheader is a struct with different types of data inside.
My code goes like this:

```
char *pStartBuffer;
memcpy(pStartBuffer, &MyHeader, MyHeader.u32Size);
```

So I want to know the length of the buffer so that I can copy the data to a file using QT write function.

```
file.write(pStartBuffer, length(pStartBuffer));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I hope your real code allocates memory for `pStartBuffer`?

Comment: And no, there's no standard way of knowing the length of the memory a pointer points to. You have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: Don't use a `char` buffer in the first place.  Use `std::string` and none of this will even be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers don't know its allocated size.

You may use `std::vector` which keep track of size for you:

```
std::vector<char> pStartBuffer(MyHeader.u32Size);
memcpy(pStartBuffer, &MyHeader, MyHeader.u32Size);
```

And latter:

```
file.write(pStartBuffer.data(), pStartBuffer.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find the length of a buffer given nothing but a pointer.  If you are *certain* that it's a string you can use one of the string length functions, or you can keep track of the length of the buffer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

*Pointer* doesn't have a "length". What you need is the length of the array which the pointer points to.

No, you cannot extract that information from the pointer.

**If** the array contains a valid, null-terminated character string, then you can get the length of that string by iterating it until you find a null character which is what `strlen` does.

If not, then what you normally do is you store the length in a variable when you allocate the array. Which is one of the things that `std::vector` or `std::string` will do for you, whichever is more appropriate for your use.